# How to inject Mocks into LWC Controller AuraEnabled static methods

Tags: apex, unit-test, bestpractice

I have an `Apex` controller for an `LWC`, something like this:

```
public with sharing class MyController {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static string getSomething() {

        try {
            MyService service = new MyService();
            return service.getSomething();
        } catch (Exception cause) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The service class has two constructors:

```
public with sharing class MyService{

    private IMyDataAccess dataAccess;

    public MyService(IMyDataAccess dataAccess) {
        this.dataAccess = dataAccess;
    }

    public MyService() {
        this.dataAccess = new MyDataAccess();
    }
}
```

Where the first constructor is used to pass in a `Mock` dependency based on the `IMyDataAccess` interface.

But `LWC` controllers use `static` methods, so at that point in the call stack I am unable to pass in the `Mock` during a test context, without polluting my code with lots of:

```
Test.isRunningTest();
```

Currently, I've created a `ServiceLocator` class:

```
public with sharing class ServiceLocator {

    public static MyService getMyService() {

        // yuck!... 
        if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
            return new MyService(new MyDataAccessMock());
        }
        return new MyService();
    }
}
```

Which encapsulates the **nasty** and **bad practice** test code in it.

But surely there is a better way?!

I looked at `Test.setMock` but that is purely for `HTTP` mocking.

1. What alternative approaches are there?
2. What is the correct/best approach for this?

Answer (score 4):

After a little more searching, I found this article:

- [Unit Testing, Apex Enterprise Patterns and ApexMocks – Part 1](https://andyinthecloud.com/2015/03/22/unit-testing-with-apex-enterprise-patterns-and-apexmocks-part-1/)

And reviewed the example code here:

- [fflib_Application](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common/blob/master/sfdx-source/apex-common/main/classes/fflib_Application.cls)

Which gave me inspiration for this:

```
public with sharing class ServiceLocator {

    private static Map<Type, Object> mockLookup = new Map<Type, Object>();

    @TestVisible
    private static void setMock(Type serviceType, Object serviceImpl) {
        mockLookup.put(serviceType, serviceImpl);
    }

    public static Object getInstance(Type serviceType) {
        if (mockLookup.containsKey(serviceType)) {
            return mockLookup.get(serviceType);
        }
        return serviceType.newInstance();
    }

    public static MyService getMyService() {
        return (MyService) getInstance(MyService.class);
    }
}
```

Now the `Apex` controller can stay clean:

```
public with sharing class MyController {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static string getSomething() {

        try {
            MyService service = ServiceLocator.getMyService();
            return service.getSomething();
        } catch (Exception cause) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And I can set the `Mock` in the unit test like this:

```
@isTest
public class MyControllerTest {

    @isTest
    static void getSomething_test() {

        // arrange
        ServiceLocator.setMock(MyService.class, new MyService(new MyDataAccessMock()));

        // act
        String actual = MyController.getSomething();

        // assert
        System.assertNotEquals(null, actual);
    }
}
```

Which means no more uses of:

```
Test.isRunningTest();
```

Yay!

Comment: Makes sense to me... I usually compress that pattern further. `MyService` can have a `.construct()` method which returns a new instance under normal circumstances, however can also return a mock if one has been set. Then anywhere in the code where I would construct `MyService`, I replace it with `.construct()`.

Comment: +1 for researching fflib mocking pattern